# cakephp 2.0 joins

Tags: cakephp, join, cakephp-2.0

I have a table 'menu_items_articles' wich are related to 'menu_items' and 'articles'.
The 'articles' table has a HABTM relation with 'tags' and 'menu_items'

Now I want to get all the 'articles' with a specific menu_tems.id and al its related 'tags'.

If an 'article' has 4 tags the array countains 4 times the article. I want 1 time the Article with all the tags related. And there's only one Tag associated with the article

This is what I have

```
$this->MenuItemsArticle->recursive = -1;

    $options['joins'] = array(
        array('table' => 'articles_tags',
            'alias' => 'ArticlesTag',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array(
            'ArticlesTag.article_id = MenuItemsArticle.article_id'
        )
    ),
        array('table' => 'articles',
            'alias' => 'Article',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array(
            'ArticlesTag.article_id = Article.id'
        )
    ),
        array('table' => 'tags',
            'alias' => 'Tag',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array(
            'ArticlesTag.tag_id = Tag.id'
        )
    )
);

$options['conditions'] = array(
    'MenuItemsArticle.menu_item_id' => $menu_item
);

$options['fields'] = array('DISTINCT MenuItemsArticle.*',' Article.*','Tag.*');


$this->paginate = $options; 
$result = $this->paginate('MenuItemsArticle');
```

Comment: It makes it confusing when you say "table", but then list the model name and visa versa.

Answer (score 0):

That's normal for Joins - just add a ['group'](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) option (GROUP BY in MySQL).

Comment: This works but I stil get only one result in the tags array() although the article contains more.

Comment: Post the mysql query generated.

Comment: `SELECT 'MenuItemsArticle'.'id', 'Article'.*, 'Tag'.'id' FROM 'database'.'menu_items_articles' AS 'MenuItemsArticle' inner JOIN 'database'.'articles_tags' AS 'ArticlesTag' ON ('ArticlesTag'.'article_id' = 'MenuItemsArticle'.'article_id') inner JOIN 'database'.'articles' AS 'Article' ON ('ArticlesTag'.'article_id' = 'Article'.'id') inner JOIN 'database'.'tags' AS 'Tag' ON ('ArticlesTag'.'tag_id' = 'Tag'.'id') WHERE 'Article'.'content_type' = 'blog' AND 'MenuItemsArticle'.'menu_item_id' = 8 GROUP BY 'Article'.'id' LIMIT 20`